# Finding the neighbors of a node/vertex in a 2D mesh

Tags: c++, graph, nodes, element, mesh

I have a 2D mesh defined by nodes and elements.

Structure of a node: Node ID, X position, Y position

Structure of an element: Element ID, Node 1, Node 2, Node 3, Node 4

Example of a 2x2 elements mesh:

```
Nodes:

 ID  X  Y
  1  0  0
  2  0  1
  3  0  2
  4  1  0
  5  1  1
  6  1  2
  7  2  0
  8  2  1
  9  2  2

Elements:

 ID N1 N2 N3 N4
  1  1  2  4  5
  2  2  3  5  6  
  3  4  5  7  8
  4  5  6  8  9

N7-----N8-----N9
|      |      |
|  E3  |  E4  |
|      |      |
N4-----N5-----N6
|      |      |
|  E1  |  E2  |
|      |      |
N1-----N2-----N3
```

I'm storing both nodes and elements in linked lists.

My question: **How can I find the neighbors (nodes) for an arbitrary selected node?**

The neighbors of N5, for example, would be N2, N4, N6 and N8.

*Note: This 2x2 element mesh simplified example for explanation proposes, the meshes I'm dealing with may contain several thousands of nodes and elements.
I also have been looking at some concepts of graph theory, but I'm not sure which may be the right way to go.

Comment: Are all the vertices in a plane (xy-plane)?  And, do they cover all the integer points in a region? or are they sparse?

Comment: @TravisJ Yes, they are confined to the xy plane. And the vertices may be sparse.

Comment: Are nodes neighbors if and only if they are directly above/below/right/left of each other?  (no other nodes between)  For example, if the graph only had two vertices, one at (0, 0) and one at (1, 1) would they be adjacent?  Also, do you know that your graph is connected?

Comment: @TravisJ That's why I call it a mesh and not a graph, let me explain.
I first define a set of points/nodes/vertices, these nodes may lay in any position on the xy-plane. Then I define elements, based on the nodes previously defined. In my case an element is defined with 4 nodes (any 4 nodes). Two nodes are connected if they share the same edge of an element, and two elements are connected of they share at least one node. Please note that I don't have a "edge list" at this point, just nodes and elements.

Comment: So you are trying to decide which elements (E1, E2, ...) are connected to which elements?  If so, the graph terminology that you are looking for is the dual of a planar graph.  The grid graph is the planar graph... the faces of the graph are your elements.  In the dual of a graph, faces become vertices (elements are vertices) and vertices are connected when the corresponding faces share an edge.

Answer (score 0):

It would be good to have element's vertices ordered in a way that they make closed polygon. Vertices [1, 2, 4, 5] do not uniquely define first element. From your description it can be seen that you mean that is a polygon with four vertices in order (1, 2, 5, 4). But without picture it can be also degenerated quad (1, 2, 4, 5).

Like:

```
Elements:

 ID N1 N2 N3 N4
  1  1  2  5  4
  2  2  3  6  5
  3  4  5  8  7
  4  5  6  9  8
```

If you are not sure about vertices order, than you have to check about element self-intersection, and reorder vertices to resolve intersections.

With that kind of data it is easy to find all neighbours of given node. Pass through all elements, if element contains given node, than there are two neighbours in that element, vertex before and after in a list.

For node 5, in first element there are neighbours 2 and 4, in second element there are neighbours 6 and 2, ...

If there will be lot of inquires of this kind, than it is better to make extract connectivity information in separate structure. That can be map that maps node to set of it's neighbours. To make it, pass through all elements, and for each element vertex add two neighbours in node's list.